# Is there a good source for ANSI character sets for typography testing in web design?

Tags: website-design, typography

Since clients like to see a visual example of typography I am looking for a way to test and display fonts chosen by client's that will include a full master list of all possible ANSI character sets with their unicodes but I am having trouble finding a reliable source.  My goal is to script a package that I can load on a test server that shows every font and the possible issues for their project since some clients choose to not use web fonts.  After a few Google searches I did find:

- [ANSI character set and equivalent Unicode and HTML characters](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html)
- [HTML ANSI (Windows-1252) Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp) (yeek...  w3schools and of course no unicode.)
- [ANSI Table](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php)

Is there an official list of all ANSI characters sets I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to narrow your scope.

Win 1252 is not ascii ansi, but a modified 8 bit charset. The oficial charset is here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145

The old ansi ascii charset was only 7 bit that is just 127 chars (You also can drop the first 32 chars, becouse they are not printable chars). In tis case you need to define an ascii or extended ascii charset.

The oficial 7bit ansi ascii is here: http://www.nssn.org/search/DetailResults.aspx?docid=571649&selnode= but you have to pay 60 bucks for it XoD So probably I would use the table on wikipedia or the links you have posted.

The link you have here http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php is an extension, from 128-255, you will notice that it does not include 1-127

and the first part is here: http://ascii-table.com/ascii.php